# how to make a heatmap with concrete values

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 12L, 1L, 16L, 14L, 10L, 
9L, 5L, 15L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 11L), .Label = c("All", 
"Bab", "boro", "bra", "charli", "delta", "few", "hora", "Howe", 
"ist", "kind", "Kiss", "myr", "No", "TT", "where"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1.251, -1.018, -1.074, -1.137, 1.018, 1.293, 1.022, 
    -1.008, 1.022, 1.252, -1.005, 1.694, -1.068, 1.396, 1.646, 
    1.016)), .Names = c("name", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

which looks like below

```
#     name  value
#1     Bab  1.251
#2    Kiss -1.018
#3     All -1.074
#4   where -1.137
#5      No  1.018
#6     ist  1.293
#7    Howe  1.022
#8  charli -1.008
#9      TT  1.022
#10    bra  1.252
#11   hora -1.005
#12    myr  1.694
#13    few -1.068
#14  delta  1.396
#15   boro  1.646
#16   kind  1.016
```

when I plot it

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1,y = name, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  ylab("")
```

it plots it randomly

[image]

but I want to have the same order as I have in my data. I also want to make the ylim smaller but I could not do.  I appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your name factor has its levels sortet *alphabetically*. What you want to do is reorder the levels of `name`. Do this before the plot:

```
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = df$name)
```

This will print the values as-is from bottom to top.
For top-to-bottom ordering, use

```
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = rev(df$name))
```

finally, setting "ylim" doesn't really make sense here. You might want to decrease the height of the canvas (e.g. by changing the size of the Plots pane in RStudio).

Comment: No need for `ordered =` here. That creates an "ordered factor" which is like an ordinal variable. Just setting the levels is best.

Comment: @MrFlick This won't work. I suggest you try this yourself. ordered is indeed needed to stop ggplot from sorting the levels.

Comment: I did try it. `df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = rev(df$name)); ggplot(df, aes(x = 1,y = name, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + ylab("")` The `ordered=` parameter is not needed.

Comment: @AlexR thanks it seems great what if you have 5 columns in your data for example look at this data here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904379/how-can-i-plot-several-heatmaps-close-together  . also is it possible to guide me how to change the color ?

Comment: @nik Check the documentation. Relevant functions are facet_grid and scale_color_continuous.

Comment: @MrFlick My bad, I always assumed ggplot was the culprit in sorting factors alphabetically. Although I'm pretty sure I had a similar problem at work wich didn't get solved without setting ordered = TRUE -- maybe ggplot2 has changed since then. Thank you for pointing it out to me :)

Comment: @AlexR I found that I can use 'scale_colour_gradient(low = "white", high = "black")' but do you know where to find different color names in R? for example if I want very red or very blue etc . also for my previous question, should I do it for each of the names separately ? like df$name1 <- factor(df$name1, levels = rev(df$name1)) and then for name2 and then name3 etc?

Comment: @nik  Yes and for the color names you can use "red" and "blue", or just HTML-Style colors: "#FF0000" and "#0000FF" - whatever works best for you.

Comment: @AlexR sorry for many questions , how can I make the font of names bigger or bold them ? if you just give me the function name I will search for it

Comment: @nik You might be better off searching for a ggplot cheat sheet. Fonts are part of the theme() command.

Comment: @AlexR It's been that way for a very long time. It's very unlikely that `ordered=` was ever an issue with ggplot but i'd be curious if you can find an example where it makes a difference. Nearly everything it done with the levels of the factor and whether it's an "ordered factor" shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @MrFlick I'll see if I can find the relevant code next week and double check.

Comment: @AlexR actually I tried 'scale_colour_gradient(low='white', high='grey20')' no matter what I give as low and high it shows dark blue and light blue . any suggestion ?

Comment: @nik https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf look there and see if it helps you. I'm positive that a comprehensive guide for ggplot would help you more than asking a lot of micro-questions wich will be answered in a full tutorial.